# Lets encrypt retains old ip address upon renewal

Tags: nginx, centos, lets-encrypt

I recently changed the server IP address. Lets encrypt upon renewal rewrites the nginx conf file with old IP address. I have to edit the file and replace in order for the magento site to go live. From where is renewal process picking the old ip?

Comment: Has your DNS changed to your new IP? What are you using, Certbot, dehydrated?

Comment: Yes the DNS has changed. I just checked using cat /etc/resolv.conf. I don't find traces of certbot or dehydrated. I am not sure how this was installed.